# Launching Intent cannot find Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

My program has a list of tabs that each contain a list of people.  Clicking a person should edit their details, but instead, clicking a person throws an ActivityNotFoundException.  My code that starts the edit activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my.package.EDIT");                // Person is both
intent.putExtra("my.package.PERSON", (Parcelable) myPerson);  // Parcelable and
GroupArrayAdapter.this.getContext().startActivity(intent);    // Serializable
```

Relevant part of AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="EditActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="my.package.EDIT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Why aren't you just doing this.startActivity(intent)? Can you post the logcat?

Comment: Well, this happens to be an OnClickListener.  Nothing in the logcat looks useful here.

Comment: And I'm using an OnClickListener in my ArrayAdapter rather than using onListItemClicked() in my ListActivity because myPerson is hard to get to from the ListActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways to start an Activity, either explicitly or implicitly.  Explicitly means that you use the class name directly; usually if you're calling an Activity that is within your own application, what you mean to use is the explicit method because it's far easier:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

However, if you really do mean to use implicit filtering, then your intent filter is missing something.  Every implicit intent filter requires the category `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` (with few exceptions).  Try this and see if it works:

```
<activity android:name="EditActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <action android:name="my.package.EDIT" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Suggested reading: [intent filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs).

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your Adapter, pass the context from the calling activity. Then in your adapter use context.startActivity(...);